# “The fact” vs. “The fact that”

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Can you use the phrase ”the fact” without “that”?

Consider the two sentences:

1. The fact that it’s Sunday means that I can sleep all day.
2. The fact it’s Sunday means that I can sleep all day.

Clearly the first sentence is correct and in common use. 
The second doesn’t sound right to me, but I can’t find clear evidence to prove (to someone) that it is indeed wrong.

Apart from answering, I would really like a reference, or an English rule, showing that the second is correct/incorrect.

Comment: The issue of dropping *that* is already in the GR domain. There's nothing special about *the fact that*, which is just another example. That said, *the fact that* is an idiomatic phrase.

Comment: It was problematic when I was reading books. However, the explanation makes the case better now. the fact that is **used when talking about a situation and saying that it is true** e.g. _Our decision to build the museum in Hartlepool was influenced by the fact that there were no national museums in the North East._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p238) has this entry on the expression **the fact that**:

> You can refer to a whole situation by using a clause beginning with
>   *the fact that*.
>
> - The fact that quick results are unlikely is no excuse for delay.
>
> Note that you must use *that* in clauses like these. You don't say, for
>   example, '*The fact quick results are unlikely is no excuse for delay.*'

Nevertheless, I suspect native speakers will commonly omit the *that* in informal spoken language - as I have in the preceding clause.

Comment: Interestingly, other instances of *that* are commonly omitted in both formal and informal speech without controversy. **the fact that** seems to be an idiomatic expression where *that* is never elided, even in informal speech.

Answer (score 4):

It can be omitted in informal speech, but it's usually present in writing.

Comment: Barrie's answer is spot on, and I would add that there are MANY synonyms that I would use in place of "The fact [missing that]" before trying to worry if there's a rule one way or the other. E.g. "since", "seeing as", "because".

Answer (score 2):

*The fact that* is a common construction that has gained some uses outside its original one;
it's now also widely used as a hesitation particle before a tensed clause.

I.e, instead of saying

- *He was told that the meeting is Wednesday.*
  one says
- *He was told the fact that the meeting is Wednesday.*

But this **does** change the meaning,
since the [NP Complement](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299) -- the *that*-clause following a [picture noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) --
of *fact* is **[Presupposed](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf)**, not merely asserted.

> (That means the speaker takes responsibility for the truth of the *that*-clause,
> and expects all listeners and readers to assume it also, without question.)

As to whether *that* can be deleted, normally the *that*'s necessary to mark the clause as an NP complement, which is not a terribly common construction, and therefore might not be obvious.

- *the report/story/rumor/claim/belief/fact **that** Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*
- **the report Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*
- **the story Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*
- *?*the rumor Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*
- *?*the claim Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*
- **the belief Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*
- **the fact Congress has passed the Antarctica Bill*

Answer (score 1):

Step by step :

1- "The fact (is) that it is Sunday means ..."
Very heavy, but correct : one subject, one verb, two separate propositions.

2- "The fact it is Sunday means ..."
Two uncorrelated subjects, with a verb in singular ; incorrect then.

In fact "that" is omitted in familiar speech ; "invisible but present" said Racine in his"Phèdre".

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the second part of your question, all that a reference grammar (or style manual) will do is confirm that experienced users and writers of English do what Barrie England said in his answer, namely, tend to include *that* in formal contexts and permit its omission in less formal ones.  Insofar as there is a rule here, you might say that noun that takes a *that*-phrase complement may optionally omit *that* in less formal registers.  E.g.:

- Who’d buy the story (that) you were here on time?
- Who’d buy the rumour (that) you were here on time?

This generalization correctly entails that words generally confined to higher registers are less felicitous without *that* than those just given.  E.g.:

- ? Who believed the testimony you were at the scene of the crime?
- ? Who believed the assertion you were at the scene of the crime?