# What is the correct word to follow consensus?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

When using the word *consensus* in a sentence, is it correct to say consensus *on*, *over*, or, *of*? For example if someone were to say,

> In 1960s British politics, there was consensus [correct word] the National Health Service?

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

- You may be speaking of a consensus *concerning* or *about* or *respecting* or *with regard to* the NHS—that is, a general agreement about what that institution should do or what should be done with it, or something of that sort.
- You may be speaking of a consensus *in* the NHS, some general agreement about something held by the officers staff of that institution. I daresay some might accept a consensus *among* the NHS in that sense; I wouldn't be very comfortable with that, but I'm not very knowledgeable about whether the NHS comprises in any sense a coherent body of people.

Comment: _Consensus_ is a picture noun, so it can take a complement clause. Usually this is a tensed clause, with a _that_ complementizer: _The consensus was/They reached a consensus that the roast was done._

Comment: @JohnLawler 'Picture noun' is concept I have not encountered. I am moved to echo Beckett: POZZO:Wonderful! Wonderful, wonderful sight!
*Silence*.
ESTRAGON:(*irritably*). Expand! Expand!

Comment: 'Picture noun' is a technical term, and I'm not responsible for it. But [I have expanded on it here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) already.

Comment: In general, if I use a term (say "picture noun") that anyone doesn't understand, they can just Search [user:15299 "picture noun"](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+picture+noun). That's what it says in the search box on [my ELU home page](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) (or whatever it's officially called). By now I've got [quite a few posts](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler?tab=answers&sort=votes) where I explain what I mean and what the terms I use mean.

Comment: @JohnLawler By gum, you do! ... Off topic, in search of a mnemonic I find that 15299 is the highest possible Windows System Error Code and signifies  "The requested system device cannot be found."

Comment: @StoneyB On ELU, 15299 is the highest possible GO-TO-WHEN-YOU-FEEL-TOTALLY-LOST Error Code and signifies "The explanation you so desperately need can be found here." :)

Answer (score 0):

See the [collocations](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=consensus) of *consensus* with usage examples.

The example sentence is possibly not well-structured. Your only choice seems to be ***within*** for the given structure.

> In 1960s British politics, there was consensus **within** the National Health Service.

Answer (score 0):

It's "consensus on". I've just corrected it in an academic text for publication.

Other options are possible, for example a Google search for "consensus regarding" get half a million hits, whereas "consensus concerning"only gets 120,000 or so, perhaps because people don't like repeating "con-" twice in succession.

Trust me, I'm a translator :-)

Comment: Traduttore, traditore.