# Use of That-clause with Certain Nouns

Tags: word-usage

Can *rule* be followed by a *that*-clause like *possibility* can?

Are both of the following sentences correct:

1. There is a possibility that life exists on other planets.
2. There is a rule that people take their shoes off before entering a place of worship.

Comment: Yes, with certain nouns. Specifically, with [the class of noun called _Picture Nouns_,](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) which are related to predicates that take complements, like _possible_ (_It's possible that it will rain today_). When nouns are derived from such predicates, they may inherit the predicate's complement-taking ability.

Comment: @JohnLawler But what such predicate is _rule_ related to? I can't think of any…

Comment: The verb _rule_, as in _The court rules that `S`_

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. That is a common construction. (See [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%20is%20a%20rule%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThere%20is%20a%20rule%20that%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: I'm wondering what the grammar term for this kind of that-clause is.

Comment: It's called a noun phrase complement, or NP complement. They're just predicate complement clauses with a noun related to a complement-taking verb. Ross discusses them in [his dissertation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html).

Answer (score -1):

"It is said that...", "It is true that..."

Yes, a very common construction.

Comment: _Be true_ and _be said_ are verb phrases; verb phrases frequently take _that_ complements. Noun phrases, not so much.