# Can I use a reflexive pronoun in the same sentence with the person represented by the pronoun?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

This is the sentence:

> The image on the screen stares back at Susan with eerie intensity – it
>   is a picture of herself

Microsoft Word would like me to say *her*, not *herself*.

Comment: "her" sounds better than "herself" to me, but I think "herself" is also acceptable.

Comment: I actually think both "her" and "herself" are correct. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: *herself* might be less ambiguous too.  Consider an example where she refers to her ex-boyfriend's new girlfriend as a derisive "*her*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picture nouns are a well-known special case for reflexivization, and possibly your grammar checker has special rules built in about that case. Do a web search for "picture nouns reflexivization" and you'll get lots of references.  But no one understands reflexivization very well, and I certainly wouldn't accept the judgement of a grammar checker.  In your example, both reflexive and non-reflexive forms sound okay, to me.

Comment: Right. They both sound OK to me, too. This is one of the many peculiarities of [Picture Nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299).