# Function of genitive

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, possessives, sentence-meaning, grammatical-roles

What is the function of the genitive case in the sentence below? More precisely, what type of relationship between the two nouns does it imply?

> The man’s tale was interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The grammatical relationship is ***attributive*** and ***determinative***.  The noun *man’s* functions as an attributive modifier of the noun *tale*, which is the head noun of the entire noun phrase.  The phrase *the man’s* is itself [determinative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase#Possessive_-s_in_English), just like *the* or *a* or *this* or *that* or *Captain Stewart’s* would be.

This is no longer the genitive case of a noun or pronoun as could be found in the Old English of a millennium ago. Today it is instead a phrasal clitic. This is easily proven by noting how in phrases like *someone else’s ideas*, the clitic attaches to *else* not to *someone*.

It notably does not here function as a “possessive” in the classical sense of that term in which physical ownership (by some animate agent, usually human) is required. A tale is not a possession. It is a tale told **by** the man or even a tale **about** the man, etc. (as John Lawler observes in a comment below), not something he owns. The sentence as written does not lock down which particular functional relation the two nouns have; there just isn’t enough context for that.

You would not say that with a *dog’s breakfast* that the dog “owns” or “possesses” said mess, or that in a *storm’s approach* that the storm “possesses” an approach nor that the storm is human. It is merely an **attribute** of the storm, and the storm is no animate being. The same applies with *time’s passing*. It is attributive. It is not possessive.

Similarly, a department store’s *children’s coloring book section* is a section **containing** coloring books **for** children, books that are **for** coloring **by** children. In noun phrases like *his wife’s pictures*, it can sometimes mean that the photographs depict his wife, **not** that she owns them.

In most ways, an apostrophe-s noun phrase acts like any other noun used attributively to modify another noun, including for purposes of ordering within the noun phrase. A *dog’s kennel* may be in someone’s own backyard, and a *dog kennel* is a kennel where dogs are kept. The two forms are quite similar grammatically. If you add adjectives to those noun phrases, they go in the same place with respect to *dog’s* or *dog*: *a dilapidated dog’s kennel; a racing dog kennel; a dilapidated racing dog kennel* (with common sense telling us that the kennel does not race and that the dog is not dilapidated).

Comment: But it could mean _the tale that the man told_ or _the tale of the man's life_, among many other kinds of functional relations. [Picture nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) don't have simple relations with their complements.

Comment: @JohnLawler You're right: there are other possibilities here as well. You can't know for sure what the functional relation is. I just pointed out the picture one as being an easy example of that ambiguity.

Comment: I don't quite agree with your analysis. I'd say that "man's" is not modifier but head of the genitive NP "the man's", which is then a subject-determiner. Note that modifier and determiner are distinct functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BillJ Yeah, I felt funny calling it a modifier on it's own. Agree it's its own head.

Answer (score 2):

> *The man’s tale was interesting.*

The grammatical function of "man's" is head of the genitive NP "the man's". "Tale" is head of the matrix NP "the man's tale". Thus we have one NP functioning in the structure of another.

Strictly speaking, the genitive NP "the man's" combines the functions of determiner and complement, cf. "the tale of the man".

As a complement, it is comparable to the subject of a clause since it occurs before the head nominal as a clause subject occurs before the head VP.

For this reason the genitive NP can be referred to as a subject-determiner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where in CGEL is this talked about? Which pages?