# What does "be of" mean?

Tags: prepositions, be

I am struggling with when to use "be of", its different meanings and alternatives like "have". I did read another thread on this on this site but still not quite sure.

> These two pictures **are of** 8.5-day-old mouse embryo. ([The Economist](https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2022/08/31/mouse-embryoids-can-now-be-grown-from-stem-cells))

> The theologian Basil the Great reported that the dominant view of hell among the believers he knew **was of** a limited, “purgatorial” suffering. ([NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/10/opinion/sunday/christianity-religion-hell-bible.html))

Some definitions say "be of" means:

- possess intrinsically; give rise to. "this work is of great interest and value"
- indicating a quality or other distinguishing mark by which a person or thing is characterized, identified or described.

But both don't seem to fit the meaning in The Economist example on pictures. If we just use "have", do we lose some subtle meaning?

For the second example on dominant views of hell, does it mean the views "have a quality/element of purgatorial suffering" or "give rise to purgatorial suffering"?

Comment: If I take a picture ***of*** you. Then that picture ***is of*** you.

Comment: But that important sense of *be of* (the *mimetic* sense) takes a lot of philosophical ink to unpack or explain at all fully. And that it has certainly received, starting with Plato and Aristotle, who regarded the fine arts as generally mimetic.

Answer (score 1):

The first example could be rephrased as

> These two pictures are *pictures* of 8.5-day-old mouse embryo.

The additional "pictures" has been dropped.

To rephrase the second example similarly I would start by noting that the reference to suffering is a reference to hell, not a reference to a view. I would get

> The theologian Basil the Great reported that the dominant view of hell among the believers he knew was *hell* of a limited, “purgatorial” suffering.

This is not quite clear or grammatical, but indicates the believers thought that the suffering of souls in hell would be a limited, purgatorial suffering.

Comment: … dominant view of hell was of a hell with limited “purgatorial” suffering.

Answer (score 0):

> These two pictures **are of** 8.5-day-old mouse embryos.

You have analysed the sentence wrongly.

These two pictures = noun phrase as subject

are = copula

of =preposition

8.5-day-old mouse embryos = noun phrase as the object of the preposition "of"

**Preposition + NP = modifier**

In this case, "of 8.5-day-old mouse embryos" is the adjectival complement of "These two pictures."

Consider

These two pictures **are** 8.5-day-old mouse embryos. -> it is patently obvious that the pictures **are** photographs - they are not mouse embryos.

These two pictures **are of** 8.5-day-old mouse embryos. = These two pictures **depict** 8.5-day-old mouse embryos.

Comment: Thanks!  Then what does "of + noun phrase", the modifier, mean?  From the answer in this post, it seems to be able to mean many things including possessing, giving rise to, having some quality of (the noun phrases) and many others... ?https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to

Comment: That sounds like a new question - the short story is that "of" = from. It indicates the origin of the picture.

Comment: But only with the word _picture_. [Picture nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) have their own grammar.

Comment: @Greybeard - Surely _of_ in _a picture of_ means 'showing, depicting'?

Comment: @KateBunting :) although that fits, I think it is coincidental. I can't think of another, distinct, instance of that meaning.

Comment: The 'depicting' sense comes from the grammar of picture nouns. Picture nouns depict, and we search for the image. _Of_ has no meaning outside its use in various constructions; it's just a gear that fits a lot of other gears with particular purposes.